# Disable Flash uploader in Magento

Tags: magento-1, admin

Are there any reliable ways of disabling the Flash uploader and using the 'classic' uploader? Is this even possible without using an extension?

I'm just normally trying to upload an image via the admin - both `/var` and `/media` (and all sub-folders) are set to 777. The response I get back is:

> {"error":"File was not uploaded.","errorcode":666}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Explanation

This error comes from `Varien_File_Uploader::__construct()` in `lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php`

Here are the important parts

```
<?php

class Varien_File_Uploader
{
    /**
     * Uploaded file handle (copy of $_FILES[] element)
     *
     * @var array
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $_file;

    const TMP_NAME_EMPTY = 666;

    function __construct($fileId)
    {
        $this->_setUploadFileId($fileId);
        if(!file_exists($this->_file['tmp_name'])) {
            $code = empty($this->_file['tmp_name']) ? self::TMP_NAME_EMPTY : 0;
            throw new Exception('File was not uploaded.', $code);
        } else {
            $this->_fileExists = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Looking back up the tree you see this is called

```
$uploader = new Mage_Core_Model_File_Uploader('image');
```

Which is extended from the Varien class, so the `Varien_File_Uploader::_setUploadFileId($fileId)` will construct the `$this->_file` array based on the key `image`, in this case.

So now the problem is [why is `$_FILES['image']['tmp_name']` empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14472741/763468)

I checked the `'error'` field by temporarily replacing it with `throw new Exception('File was not uploaded. ' . $this->_file['error'], $code);`

I got 7, which is [`Failed to write file to disk. Introduced in PHP 5.1.0.`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) which means it's a permissions issue.

## Solution

Do a `phpinfo()` to check where your `upload_tmp_dir` is set to and make sure it's writable.

In my case, I was out of file space in the `/tmp` dir of my server.

Answer (score 2):

I've always used the No Flash Image Uploader, which worked with CE v1.4 - v1.7 without issue. The module is no longer available via Magento Connect, though its source code is actively maintained (as of Oct. 2016) and is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader).

You could grab the extension code and just extract the portion that you need if really necessary.

Comment: That item MageBayVaporated and seems to no longer be available.

Comment: I already installed. it's working well on product image upload, but in downloadable product file upload, it won't work.
Do you have any other alternate solution for accomplishing without flash on downloadable product page downloadable section

Answer (score 1):

I would say: "no". This is not possible out-of-the-box, <strike>but I found a plugin:</strike>

http://www.paoloiannelli.com/2012/07/30/how-to-disable-flash-uploader-magento/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, but I had an update of windows. Rebooted computer and everything worked again

Answer (score 0):

You can find here a Magento extension that allow multi-images upload using jquery and no flash : https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/multi-images-uploader-jquery-no-flash.html